# Getting discouraged (by / with / from) somebody

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

I was wondering which prepositions(s)sound(s)natural in the following scenarios:

> **Scenario 1:**

I'm your father! I want you to stop smoking, Anna. That's really harmful to your health. Sometimes, you discourage me ......... your actions.

a. with 
b. by

> **Scenario 2:**

Anna, hear me out! I've warned you several times already to stop smoking. I had told you that is rude to do that when I'm at home! But, you overlooked my request again! 
I'm really getting discouraged ....... you.

a. from 
b. by

Comment: *I want you to stop smoking Anna* - You need to rephrase this. Major, major, red buzzer! It sounds like "Anna" is a drug or something that is being smoked. You could use a comma between smoking and Anna.

Comment: Point take @AIQ. I added comma. But I have no idea how should I rephrase it in a better way! Just please kindly answer my question. :)

Comment: I have a feeling you are incorrectly using the word "discourage". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: The verb "discourage" to me means: "ruin / take someone's hopes" @AIQ.

Comment: You ignored my request + Your reaction discourages me.

Comment: The way this question is written makes it sound like you’re asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @nick012000 having a look at my records, you can easily find out that I did not have such that intent! I wonder if instead, you could help me to improve this thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the options “by” and “from”, “by” sounds better in both scenarios. Both can be be used and are still grammatically correct, and it is  your choice to decide what to use.